# Should every function which calls itself be considered a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, semantics

I understand what recursive functions are, but consider the following example of a function meant to get the local version of data on an item, check if there is new data about it available online based on locally stored cache time, and if there is, updating the local data with the new version, returning up-to-date data about it either way.

```
function getItemData(id){
    var local=getLocalItemData(id);
    if(!local.cacheTime.upToDate()){
        var newData=getOnlineItemData(id);
        updateLocalItemData(id, newData);
        return getItemData(id);
    }
    else{
        return local.returnHumanReadable();
    }
}
```

My argument against considering it a recursive function is the fact that it will only end up calling itself on rare occasions when the cache time indicates the data has expired, and that the function only calls itself for convenience.

Instead of using `return getLocalItemData(id).returnHumanReadable();` I can use `return getItemData(id);` because it will return the same result, as the newly saved data won't need to be refreshed again in the several microseconds it will take the function to call itself. Also, it is much shorter: in the actual code, I would use lower level commands instead of those function calls, resulting in code duplication which would make the entire function harder to read and maintain.

So, do you think that my argument makes any sense, or do you consider this to be nothing more than a matter of code organization?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: yes it is recursive

It becomes important if you consider a platform that does not support recursion

Since it can call itself, your code will not work on that platform because it is technically recursion

For a trivial case like this replacing the recursive call with `getLocalItemData(id).returnHumanReadable();` will allow it to work on this platform.  In fact, you can change your code to:

```
function getItemData(id){
    var local=getLocalItemData(id);
    if(!local.cacheTime.upToDate()){
        var newData=getOnlineItemData(id);
        updateLocalItemData(id, newData);
        local=getLocalItemData(id);
    }
    return local.returnHumanReadable();
}
```

**NOTE:** If you cannot 100% guarantee that only one call is needed, change the `if` to `while`

Comment: Actually, it seems to me that the function you propose is not exactly equivalent to that of the OP. You should have a real equivalence if you substitute `if` with `while`.

Comment: @Renzo i would likely code it that way, but OP asserted that it can only happen once by the substitution offered

Comment: You are right, but then the "recursivity" would be questionable, in some sense. I'll try to explain myself better: the recursivity should be more clear from a formal transformation of the function. The fact that the access to the network is needed only once because the `updateLocalItemData` is very fast is only true in this particular case, but suppose that it should take more time in future, then it could be necessary call again `getOnlineItemData`, and *this* is the essence of recursivity.  However I understand your point and your definition of the function.

Comment: Since it's tail recursion, thus an iterative process,  it can always be rewritten as an iterative solution in languages that don't do TCO.

Comment: @Renzo noted.  And yes, the true recursive to iterative transformation would use `while`

Comment: @Sylwester thats what I did